# Change background for gif animation file

Tags: android, file, animation, save, gif

I save animation file and share it with help next code:

```
try {
        //create an temp file in app cache folder
        File outputFile = new File(getCacheDir(), "animation" + ".gif");
        FileOutputStream outPutStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        //Saving the resource GIF into the outputFile:
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(getAnimationDrawableIdByMediaId(mPickedAnimationId));
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baos.write(current);
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        fos.write(baos.toByteArray());

        //
        outPutStream.flush();
        outPutStream.close();

        //share file
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(outputFile));
        shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share"));
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Toast.makeText(this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
```

But I noticed that in Telegram background of this animation is white but in Viber it is black. Is there way to set custom background color? Maybe with another implementation.

Comment: can you please post the what image background is coming and what are you expecting?

Comment: @TrickySolutions When I open this gif on PC I see white background, and I want at least see the same background in all messengers. Can I do it?

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko - Nothing is gonna get done till you post the image. Tag me once you do upload.